# Receiving an SSL connection could not be established error when using Fast.Components.FluentUI on Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-server-side, fluent-ui

NET community

When using Fast.Components.FluentUI on Blazor Server (.NET 7), I get the following error on components where the `FluentDataGrid` component is used:

```
[2023-03-24T09:47:34.226Z] Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.HttpBasedStaticAssetService.GetAsync(String assetUrl, Boolean useCache) in /_/src/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Infrastructure/HttpBasedStaticAssetService.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.FluentIcon.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in /_/src/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Components/Icon/FluentIcon.cs:line 161
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

I observed, that the FluentIcons are not displayed.
Do you have any Idea how to resolve the issue?

The error only occurs after the app has been deployed to Azure Web Services. On local development mode, everything works perfectly.

**Update [24.03.2023 @ 13:55 UTC]**

I was able to resolve the issue by replacing all `<FluentIcon />` components through classic HTML i-tag implementations (i.e. `<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>`)

Nevertheless, I'd still be interested if someone has a solution to the issue above.